# Create a select with attributes from JSON in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I would like to create a select with your attributes(select id,select class) coming from JSON (that it's defined in my controller).

There is a way to do that? Or Does I need to do dynamic partials with the code of the select?

Assuming I do not know what attributes I have in JSON.

Thanks!

**UPDATE:**

For example, if I have this JSON:

```
{ "topology" : [ 
        { "name": "id", "value":"topology_id"  },
        { "name": "class", "value": "topology_class1 topology_class2" },
        { "name": "diasbled", "value": "disabled" } 
    ]
}
```

I would like to obtain this select tag:

```
<select id="topology_id" class="topology_class1 topology_class2" disabled="disabled"></select>
```

And if I have another JSON with another attributes, then these another attributes that will be in my select tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your updated JSON file, you can do something like this:

```
// Your template
<select dynamic-attributes='topology'></select>

// The dynamic attributes directive
angular.module('yourModule')
    .directive('dynamicAttributes', ['jsonData', function (jsonData) {
        return function (scope, element, attrs) {
            // Get the attribute data from a service.
            var attributes = jsonData.get(attrs.dynamicAttributes);
            // Add each of the attributes to the element.
            attributes.forEach(function (attribute) {
                element.attr(attribute.name, attribute.value);
            });
        }
    }]);

// The jsonData service
angular.module('yourModule')
    .service('jsonData', function () {
        // This would really come from the server.
        var json = { 
            "topology" : [ 
                { "name": "id", "value":"topology_id"  },
                { "name": "class", "value": "topology_class1 topology_class2" },
                { "name": "diasbled", "value": "disabled" } 
            ]
        };

        // Public API
        return {
            get: function (name) {
                return json[name];
            }
        };
    });
```

Here's a working fiddle with the code: http://jsfiddle.net/nfreitas/SmWE8/ (don't mind the styling, it's there to show that the attributes are being added.)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but try to suppose you don't know what the attributes there are in a JSON. I would like to put all attributes, no matter what the attribute is included in JSON.

Comment: Do you have an example of the JSON?  If the JSON contains many different types of attributes, then a custom directive would probably be your best option.

Comment: I put an UPDATE in my question, please take a look. Thank you!